# How might a tabletop be joined to this kind of frame?

Tags: joinery, furniture, tabletop, table-making

I stumbled across a table [here](https://jp.mercari.com/item/m12581701379) which has a rare view of the underside of the table. Similar designs can be found by searching for: "組子テーブル".

Some photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The table seems to have effectively no apron, and sliding dovetail or cleat construction seems unlikely. From my inspection I could find no screws or nails or buttons of any kind.

What ways could this type of tabletop be attached to a subframe like this? I have looked at as many Japanese joinery/furniture making resources as I can and none cover anything like this.

Comment: Magic? :-) Not sure if you'll get the answer to this here, due to the limited number of members (and the even smaller number who visit regularly and post). Although there's always the chance someone can do some Internet sleuthing and find something relevant. We can speculate of course, but the photos are frustratingly just a bit too small and not quite sharp enough to see details clearly (which might have added info we could extrapolate from.). Anyway, my speculation is that the legs may simply be glued into shallow mortises in the tabletop frame. Note that the top isn't solid wood... [contd]

Comment: ...it's a frame surrounding what looks to be a plywood panel underlying the kumiko. That might seem weak, and it would be weaker than we'd normally expect to see (although standards for that vary wildly with furniture type and level) but joined to the gallery elements I could see this easily be strong enough for service in the type of home that would have a piece like this, especially as I imagine the 'rails' mortise into all legs so the structure can work together as a single unit. Additionally, glueing the top rail of all four gallery elements is possible, and would add even more strength.

Comment: _Appreciates that @Graphus wants to give everyone else a chance. Wishes he would just write answers in the answer box instead of in comments._

Comment: @FreeMan, :-) The point in this case was that I took it from the wording of the Q that the OP actually wanted to know how this table was constructed, not how it *might* be. It's very easy to suggest alternative possibility, and I'm sure NBoss had at least one or two thoughts of their own, but none of those guesses could be close to the truth (although many/most could be viable alternatives naturally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are accepting Answers about how this *might* be done, I'll convert my Comments to offer another viable suggestion.

First off take note that the main field of the tabletop appears to be a plywood panel, which allows for the outer frame and the attachment of a solid leg assembly *without accommodation for wood movement* as you probably should with any solid-wood top of these dimensions.

Although there appear to be no fasteners used, they could be there but hidden by wooden plugs or even filler. However this design can be built using only simple joinery and glue without too much difficulty.

My thought on the construction was that the legs may simply be glued into mortises in the tabletop frame, or alternatively have stub tenons formed on their ends. I don't think there's a good reason to prefer one over the other for a table of this kind, which must be treated with care and respect — this would not be a suitable choice for the busy living room of a family with boisterous kids!

Glueing the legs directly into shallow mortises might seem weak, and it would be weaker than we'd normally expect to see (although standards for that vary wildly with furniture type and level<sup>1</sup>), but joined to the gallery elements I could see this easily being strong enough for service in the type of home that would have a piece like this, especially as I imagine the 'rails' are mortised into all legs so the understructure can work together as a single unit.

Additionally, glueing the top rail of all four gallery elements is possible, and would add even more strength<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> What we might call 'art furniture' is sometimes built with looks first and structural integrity or outright strength second (or third or fourth!). Note that it's still common to see handmade furniture finished in shellac and wax, or just oiled, when factory stuff has nearly always had a lacquer or varnish finish for nearly 100 years now.

<sup>2</sup> Remembering that glued long-grain surfaces like this are stronger than the wood itself.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think the middle of the tabletop is plywood? I highly doubt that it is as 1. Most Japanese timbers are lighter than plywood and 2. With the thickness of the acrylic plate, the latticework and the grid on the underside, there doesn't seem to be much room left for a load-bearing panel.

Other things to consider are that if the table is something like Japanese cedar, then the dead load of the table is tiny due to low density, and the lattices on the top and bottom of the tabletop will add significant stiffness. (not to mention the gallery joints you've talked about)

Comment: Because it's a modern piece, not using trad joinery or materials throughout is a definite possibility (many modern Japanese makers are perfectly happy to eschew tradition as and when it suits them). But mainly because it looks like veneer on the underside :-) Hard to be sure from the photos of course because of the size and lighting. It IS possible that is a glued-up panel (making it a floating element to allow for movement) but if that's the case it would appear the grain runs 90° to what you'd expect to see, *maximising* expansion/contraction rather than minimising it.

Comment: *"Most Japanese timbers are lighter than plywood"* Well many Japanese furniture woods are famous for being lightweight, true, but this does depends on the plywood doesn't it? Plenty of softwood ply made today, and in Asia there could be types unavailable in the West (made for a more localised market) that utilise lighter-weight hardwood species. That aside, I was presuming the main body of the piece was made from either one of the same woods the Chinese use for this type of thing (e.g. huanghuali) or a similar Japanese domestic equivalent, although that could easily be an erroneous guess.

Answer (score 4):

A large round tenon at the 4 corners and small dowels on the top rails on the sides would be sufficient to hold the tabletop tight against the supports.

Added information:
People were wondering why I stated a round tenon verse a more acceptable square tenon.  After creating the shallow round mortise at each of the 4 corners of the tabletop, the legs will have matching round tenons. The round tenon allows the legs to be slightly rotated to align the squareness of the leg with the tabletop edge.  Both round and square tenon can be used to produce perfectly aligned edges, but the round mortise/tenon provides one additional aid to align the edges/surfaces without having to make fine adjustments to the tenon or mortise and leaving a gap between the two.

Comment: Round, square, the tenon shape probably won't matter much. I'd imagine that all the joints are mortise & tenon. For such short legs and the fact that people _probably_ don't push against the table too much, the very short tenon that you'd be able to get into the fairly thin top would probably be sufficient.

Comment: I have several pieces of Chinese made furnitures and the tenons were round, even with the legs squared.

Comment: Considering similar tables are held together by only a triple mitre joint, I'm inclined to think that the joinery here is a variation of that joint. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that those rails were only joined with glue.

Comment: Interesting, @Programmer66

Comment: Not to take anything away from your suggested option, but this table is presumably Japanese and therefore the joinery (IF some type of traditional form, which it could very well *not* be) might be quite different from what's seen in Chinese furniture.